# Usando o select para abrir iframe

Tags: html, html5, select, iframe

Tenho um código e quero que ele abra um caminho no `iframe` quando eu clico em um `option` do `select`. Consegui fazer isso, porém para mudar a opção para que ele abra outra coisa no `iframe` eu tenho que atualizar a página. Se eu clicar em um e depois quiser mudar para outro não acontece.

Vou colar o código para vocês darem uma olhada:

```
<form>
    <select name="Exames" onChange="abrir.location = options[selectedIndex].value">
        <option label="Selecione sua opção" value="0"></option>
        <option value="https://www.youtube.com/?gl=BR&hl=pt">opção1</option>
        <option value="https://www.google.com.br/">opção2</option>
    </select>
</form>

<iframe id="abrir" name="abrir" scrolling="auto" src=""></iframe>
```

Comment: Você está verificando se de fato o src do iframe recebe o value quando tenta a segunda vez?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caso queira utilizar jquery atribua um id ao seu select

```
$("#Exames").change(function(){ 
  var url = $(this).val();
  $("#abrir").attr("src",url); 
});
```

Caso queira javascript puro mude para isso

```
onChange="document.getElementById('abrir').src = this.Exames[this.selectedIndex].value
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer com Jquery:

```
$('select').on('change',function(){
   var src = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
   $('#abrir').attr('src',src);
});
```

**Atenção:** Alguns sites enviam `"X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN"` como cabeçalho de resposta, isto evita que o navegador exiba `iframes` que não estão hospedados no mesmo domínio que a página pai, no caso o Youtube e o Google, que você colocou no `select`, não abrirão:

[Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/7QZcP/1/)